# Appending a new key into a existing array

Tags: php, arrays

it may seem to be a silly question, but i dont know why, this thing isn't working for me.

I have an exisiting array

```
$data = array(
                'first_name' => $first_name,
                'last_name' => $last_name,
                'email' => $email,
                'password' => $enc_password,
                'date_of_adding' => date('d/m/Y'),
                'support_timestamp' => $timestamp
            );
```

now i want to insert or append a new key with value into this existing array.

where the new key and its value is

```
'username' => $username
```

what i did is that

```
$data['username'] = $username;
```

but still the thing isn't working.

Can anybody tell what i am doing wrong??

Comment: It should work. Post your complete code. Or create a simple fiddle reprducing it.

Comment: work fine for me . what you get on doing var_dump($data).

Comment: Does the variable `$username` have a value?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  $data = array(
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name,
            'email' => $email,
            'password' => $enc_password,
            'date_of_adding' => date('d/m/Y'),
            'support_timestamp' => $timestamp
        );

$data2 = array('username'=>$username);
$data = array_unshift($data,$data2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do like this:

$data[]=array('username' => $username)
```

It will append the new array into an existing array

Answer (score 0):

It should work using `$data['username'] = $username;`

[Have a look at it here.](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn/%2a%20Original%20array%20%2a/%5Cn%24data%20=%20array%28%5Cn%5Ct%27first_name%27%20=%3E%20%22a%22,%5Cn%5Ct%27last_name%27%20=%3E%20%22b%22,%5Cn%5Ct%27email%27%20=%3E%20%22c%22,%5Cn%5Ct%27password%27%20=%3E%20%22d%22,%5Cn%5Ct%27support_timestamp%27%20=%3E%20%22e%22%5Cn%29;%5Cn%5Cn/%2a%20Add%20new%20key%20%2a/%5Cn%24data%5B%27test%27%5D%20=%20%22sdfsdf%22;%5Cn%5Cn%5Cnvar_dump%28%24data%29;%5Cn?%3E) Click the run icon

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
$data2 = array('username'=>$username);
$data = array_push($data,$data2);
```

or visit

[demo](https://www.php.net/array_push)